# Is there a super() in Object class also,if so where does it poin?

Tags: java

`super()` is implicitly placed in every constructor so that it acquires the methods mentioned in the parent class. The highest class in hierarchy is `Object`.

Question is where the `super()` of `Object` class point to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might find this interesting.

```
System.out.println("System.class.getSuperclass()= "+System.class.getSuperclass());
System.out.println("Object.class.getSuperclass()= "+Object.class.getSuperclass());
```

prints

```
System.class.getSuperclass()= class java.lang.Object
Object.class.getSuperclass()= null
```

Answer (score 2):

It's instructive to check out the [source code for Object](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html)

As you can see, it doesn't have a base class (note that implicitly the base class would be `Object` but how can that be in this case?)

As noted in the code comments, it's the root of the Java hierarchy. As such, it's a special case and doesn't have a superclass invocation.

Answer (score 2):

The Object class cannot have a super() it is the highest item in the class hierarchy. Everything below it will have a super() but not Object.

Answer (score 2):

See [12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.5) of the JLS

> If this constructor is for a class other than `Object`, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using `super`).

Answer (score 1):

There would be no super in Object.

Answer (score 1):

The object class is in the base of the all classes in java so there will not any call of super() in the constructor of object class.

**It does not extended by any class so its obvious that it do not call super in its constructor.**

Answer (score 0):

Think as the chain stops at Object.

Like A **->** super() **->** B->super() **->** stop

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by writing two classes and extending one class from another

Ex:

Create class A as:

```
class A{

   int a, b;

   A(int a, int b){
   }

}
```

Create class B which extends class A:

```
class B extends A{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        B b = new B();
    } 
}
```

You will get an error while you try to create an object of class B, because the class B default constructor gets called and which intrun calls default constructor of the super class "A", but the class A does not have any default or zero parameter constructor.